# How to send Application to background after some specific time

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am using the following code to minimize my app

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

but now I want to minimize my app after some specific time. I mean my app should minimize automatically after 40 - 60 secs etc. I am trying to achieve this through AlarmManager but it is not working.

How I can send my activity to background?

Comment: What does "minimize" mean? You want your app to exit automatically?

Comment: nope.just to hide my app and bring home infront of the screen but when someone starts the app again,it should start from the place where one left it not from the start.

Comment: Thats where using the onPause, onStop, and onDestroy methods of an activity would come into play. You could save the state of activity in onPause or onStop and then implement that state to be reinstated in your onResume.

Comment: James is right; Android really doesn't have any concept of an activity being in the "background" -- or at any rate, there's no way to "send" it there. If you know of some other activity you would like to appear on top of yours, there are probably ways to arrange it, but that's probably not what you want. What you want to do is save your state as James describes and restore it again in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in MainActivity.java

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                test();
            }
        });
    }              
}, 0, 20000);
```

The above code will call `test()` function after 20 second.. Now write the following function...

```
public void test()
{ 
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Hope this will help.